# Codename One Android sendMessage HTML

Tags: android, html, gmail, codenameone, message

My app compiles and sends an HTML message with the following code:

```
String s = ...; // html text with normal & bold face, proportional & monospaced fonts, etc.
Message msg = new Message(s);
msg.setMimeType(Message.MIME_HTML);
sendMessage(subject, msg, recipients);
```

On iOS (iPhone X) this works, the Mail app opens with a correct html rendering of the text.

On Android (Samsung Tab A) this doesn't work:

- Gmail app: shows plain text with newlines (no bold face etc.)
- Email app (Samsung): plain text without newlines (dito)

(In the simulator with an email client I see the correct html source text.)

How can this be solved?

Perhaps this is related to https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3101.

**EDIT**

Tested with the following HTML example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Example</h2>
Text with <b>bold</b> and <i>italics</i>.<br>
This text on a new line.
</body>
</html>
```

With the following output (screenshots of reading the sent mails):

[image: Output]

By the way, when sending plain text instead of HTML, newlines don't show up in Gmail while they do in Samsung Email (see issue 3101).

Comment: How does the HTML look? If the `<br>` is respected then why the `<b>`or `<strong>` wouldn't be?

Comment: I have added an HTML example to my question (see EDIT) with the three different outputs. Is it possible that this used to work and now doesn't because of a recent change?

Comment: Looking a bit at Android code that uses this approach I noticed most developers don't use the full HTML only a subset when creating the email e.g. `<h2>Example</h2>
Text with <b>bold</b> and <i>italics</i>.<br>
This text on a new line.`

Comment: I tried that and the output is exactly the same. I filed an issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3386.

Comment: That's very odd. I looked at the code for similar questions and our code does exactly the same thing under the hood. It also looks like the HTML is partially accepted in gmail as the Example is separated and newline is accepted. It seems that just the formatting itself is ignored which makes me think this is a gmail html issue

Comment: It is partly a Gmail HTML issue (they removed HTML support, as it seems) and partly a CN1 issue, for e-mail clients that do support HTML. I got it to work for Samsung Email, see my Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that things have changed quite a bit over the years.
`Html.fromHtml` is deprecated for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24`.
It now requires an extra flag parameter, `Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY`.
However, the old version is still supported and does exactly that.
There is also a version `HtmlCompat.fromHtml`, which is equivalent.
Class Html supports a HTML subset, e.g. `<b>`, `<i>` and `<font>` are supported but not `<html>` and `<body>`.

Next, the recommended way to send an html message has changed.
Instead of using type `"text/html"`, parameter `EXTRA_TEXT` and method `fromHtml`,
we should use type `"text/plain"`, supply a plain text using parameter `EXTRA_TEXT` (see below)
**and** supply the **raw HTML source text** using parameter `EXTRA_HTML_TEXT`.
Email clients that support (full) HTML will use `EXTRA_HTML_TEXT`, Email clients that don't fall back to `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Then, it appears that **Google has removed HTML support for Gmail** a few years ago (*why??*).
Using the above method, Gmail falls back to `EXTRA_TEXT` while *Samsung Email* supports `EXTRA_HTML_TEXT` and that gives *correctly rendered HTML!*

What happens in Gmail is that HTML input is "sanitized", which seems to mean that only plain text comes out,
with appropriate line breaks for `<h1>`, `<br>`, etc. No other formatting such as bold, italics or fonts is supported.
The `Html.fromHtml` method is still useful to create the `EXTRA_TEXT` fallback text for Gmail.

I tried many things using native code for Android but I could not get Gmail to render HTML correctly.
I found a few different ways to get it working in Samsung Email; I will present the one that I think is how it should be done.

**Conclusion**

The code below is a workaround for issues
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3101 and
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3386.

If you want to send HTML formatted text this will work in some e-mail clients (such as Samsung Email) and not in others (most notably Gmail). In the latter case you have to settle for sending plain text with some line break formatting only.

If you want to send a mail containing plain text with line breaks, generate a String containing the text and `<br>` tags only, and
send this as HTML using the code below. This gives the correct result in both Samsung Email and Gmail.

```
package com.xx.yy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Html;

import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import com.codename1.impl.android.IntentResultListener;
import com.codename1.io.Log;

public class AndroidNativeInterfaceImpl {

    // adapted from com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.sendMessage()
    // pass HTML String, not Message; no attachments
    public void sendHTMLMessage(String recipient, String subject, String msg) {

        String[] recipients = new String[] { recipient };

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

        // deprecated
        //emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(msg));

        // new
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(msg, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)); // fallback text for e.g. Gmail
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, msg); // raw (full) HTML for e.g. Samsung Email

        AndroidNativeUtil.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), new IntentResultListener() {
            public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                Log.p("native sendHTMLMessage done");
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Some useful links**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java

[Android - Send email with styled HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768440/android-send-email-with-styled-html)

[Has Android's Gmail app removed the ability to send HTML emails via Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382912/has-androids-gmail-app-removed-the-ability-to-send-html-emails-via-intent)

[Sending HTML based email body using android intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556498/sending-html-based-email-body-using-android-intent)